# Accuracy of stereovision camera

Tags: stereo-vision

I want to use stereovision to get 3D coordinates of a point in the camera's frame. Let's say, I can zoom in and click in the image to select my point of interest.

1. I want an accuracy of about 0.05 - 0.1mm. How do I select such a stereo camera? I checked a few stereocam specs but I didnt see any specification called 'accuracy' in it.
2. Is there some way to compute the accuracy from all other specs mentioned in the list?

I was looking at this camera
http://files.carnegierobotics.com/products/MultiSense_S7/MultiSense_Stereo_brochure.pdf